# cocos2d - addchild class derived from CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i'm beginner for cocos2d-iphone.

i have a problem with addchild to gamescene.

i made a simple class derived from CCSprite and i've tried to display this class.

but it didn't work and i don't know what is problem.

this is my code of class:

```
//myClass.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface myClass:CCSprite{
}
@end

//myClass.m
#import "myClass.h"
@implementation myClass
-(id) init{
    if( self = [super initWithFile:@"title.png"] ){
        self.position = ccp(240, 240);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and this is a part of gamescene:

```
//HelloWorldLayer.m
...
// this worked well.
// myClass* temp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"title.png"];
// temp.position = ccp(240, 240);
// [self addChild:temp];

// but this won't work.
myClass* temp = [[myClass alloc] init];
[self addChild:temp];
...
```

what should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the code, initWithFile calls initWithTexture that calls init, so you are in a loop and that's cause the problem. Try to make another constructor or a class method that creates your sprite and set position.

For example

```
//myClass.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface myClass:CCSprite{
}
-(id)initMy;
+(id)createMySprite;
@end

//myClass.m
#import "myClass.h"
@implementation myClass
-(id) initMy{
    if( self = [super initWithFile:@"title.png"] ){
        self.position = ccp(240, 240);
    }
    return self;
}
+(id)createMySprite {
    return [[[self alloc] initMy] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Comment: holy god! you saved me from hell! Thank you very much!